# How Do I Map through nested Arrays in JavaScript and then check if one of the Nested Array's properties does not have a value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array of objects and each one of these objects has a nested array of `programs` with a key called `programId`.

```js
[{
    "roleId": 1,
    "code": "ORGAOR",
    "parentOrgId": null,
    "description": "Authorized Organization Representative",
    "displayText": "Authorized Organization Representative",
    "programs": [{
      "programId": 14,
      "programName": null,
      "programStatusId": null,
      "programTypeId": null,
      "startDate": null,
      "endDate": null,
      "financialAbbreviationCode": null,
      "cfdaNumber": null,
      "divisionDeptAcronym": null,
      "originalProgramId": null,
      "programDescription": null,
      "disasterFlag": null,
      "programOfficeId": null,
      "organizationId": null
    }]
  },
  {
    "roleId": 1,
    "code": "ORGAOR",
    "parentOrgId": null,
    "description": "Authorized Organization Representative",
    "displayText": "Authorized Organization Representative",
    "programs": [{
      "programId": 15,
      "programName": null,
      "programStatusId": null,
      "programTypeId": null,
      "startDate": null,
      "endDate": null,
      "financialAbbreviationCode": null,
      "cfdaNumber": null,
      "divisionDeptAcronym": null,
      "originalProgramId": null,
      "programDescription": null,
      "disasterFlag": null,
      "programOfficeId": null,
      "organizationId": null
    }]
  },
  {
    "roleId": 1,
    "code": "ORGAOR",
    "parentOrgId": null,
    "description": "Authorized Organization Representative",
    "displayText": "Authorized Organization Representative",
    "programs": [{
      "programId": 17,
      "programName": null,
      "programStatusId": null,
      "programTypeId": null,
      "startDate": null,
      "endDate": null,
      "financialAbbreviationCode": null,
      "cfdaNumber": null,
      "divisionDeptAcronym": null,
      "originalProgramId": null,
      "programDescription": null,
      "disasterFlag": null,
      "programOfficeId": null,
      "organizationId": null
    }]
  },
  {
    "roleId": 21,
    "code": "SUBAUTHREP",
    "parentOrgId": "-50022",
    "description": "Subrecipient Authorized Representative",
    "displayText": "Subrecipient Authorized Representative",
    "programs": [{
      "programId": 16,
      "programName": null,
      "programStatusId": null,
      "programTypeId": null,
      "startDate": null,
      "endDate": null,
      "financialAbbreviationCode": null,
      "cfdaNumber": null,
      "divisionDeptAcronym": null,
      "originalProgramId": null,
      "programDescription": null,
      "disasterFlag": null,
      "programOfficeId": null,
      "organizationId": null
    }]
  },
]
```

I want to map through the `programs` and check to make sure that the `programId` has a value. Here is what I have so far:

```js
updateUser = async (selectedUser) => {
    const {roles} = selectedUser;
    const newRoles =  roles.map((role) => {
      return role.programs;
    })
    console.log(newRoles);
 };
```

Where do I go from here?

Comment: Do you just want to know if *any* `programId` value is `null`, or do you want to know the specific `programId` values that are `null`?

Comment: @Nick I just want to know if any `programId` is null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

```
const missingProgramID = roles.some(({programs})=>
    programs.some(({programId})=>programId==null));
```

Demo:

```js
let roles = [{
    "roleId": 1,
    "code": "ORGAOR",
    "parentOrgId": null,
    "description": "Authorized Organization Representative",
    "displayText": "Authorized Organization Representative",
    "programs": [{
      "programId": 14,
      "programName": null,
      "programStatusId": null,
      "programTypeId": null,
      "startDate": null,
      "endDate": null,
      "financialAbbreviationCode": null,
      "cfdaNumber": null,
      "divisionDeptAcronym": null,
      "originalProgramId": null,
      "programDescription": null,
      "disasterFlag": null,
      "programOfficeId": null,
      "organizationId": null
    }]
  },
  {
    "roleId": 1,
    "code": "ORGAOR",
    "parentOrgId": null,
    "description": "Authorized Organization Representative",
    "displayText": "Authorized Organization Representative",
    "programs": [{
      "programId": 15,
      "programName": null,
      "programStatusId": null,
      "programTypeId": null,
      "startDate": null,
      "endDate": null,
      "financialAbbreviationCode": null,
      "cfdaNumber": null,
      "divisionDeptAcronym": null,
      "originalProgramId": null,
      "programDescription": null,
      "disasterFlag": null,
      "programOfficeId": null,
      "organizationId": null
    }]
  },
  {
    "roleId": 1,
    "code": "ORGAOR",
    "parentOrgId": null,
    "description": "Authorized Organization Representative",
    "displayText": "Authorized Organization Representative",
    "programs": [{
      "programId": 17,
      "programName": null,
      "programStatusId": null,
      "programTypeId": null,
      "startDate": null,
      "endDate": null,
      "financialAbbreviationCode": null,
      "cfdaNumber": null,
      "divisionDeptAcronym": null,
      "originalProgramId": null,
      "programDescription": null,
      "disasterFlag": null,
      "programOfficeId": null,
      "organizationId": null
    }]
  },
  {
    "roleId": 21,
    "code": "SUBAUTHREP",
    "parentOrgId": "-50022",
    "description": "Subrecipient Authorized Representative",
    "displayText": "Subrecipient Authorized Representative",
    "programs": [{
      "programId": 16,
      "programName": null,
      "programStatusId": null,
      "programTypeId": null,
      "startDate": null,
      "endDate": null,
      "financialAbbreviationCode": null,
      "cfdaNumber": null,
      "divisionDeptAcronym": null,
      "originalProgramId": null,
      "programDescription": null,
      "disasterFlag": null,
      "programOfficeId": null,
      "organizationId": null
    }]
  },
]
let missingProgramID = roles.some(({programs})=>
    programs.some(({programId})=>programId==null));
console.log("Missing program id?", missingProgramID);
delete roles[0].programs[0].programId;
missingProgramID = roles.some(({programs})=>
    programs.some(({programId})=>programId==null));
console.log("Missing program id (after deleting property)?", missingProgramID);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```
roles.some(r => r.programs.some(p => p.programId === null))
```

```js
let roles = [{
    "roleId": 1,
    "code": "ORGAOR",
    "parentOrgId": null,
    "description": "Authorized Organization Representative",
    "displayText": "Authorized Organization Representative",
    "programs": [{
      "programId": 14,
      "programName": null,
      "programStatusId": null,
      "programTypeId": null,
      "startDate": null,
      "endDate": null,
      "financialAbbreviationCode": null,
      "cfdaNumber": null,
      "divisionDeptAcronym": null,
      "originalProgramId": null,
      "programDescription": null,
      "disasterFlag": null,
      "programOfficeId": null,
      "organizationId": null
    }]
  },
  {
    "roleId": 1,
    "code": "ORGAOR",
    "parentOrgId": null,
    "description": "Authorized Organization Representative",
    "displayText": "Authorized Organization Representative",
    "programs": [{
      "programId": 15,
      "programName": null,
      "programStatusId": null,
      "programTypeId": null,
      "startDate": null,
      "endDate": null,
      "financialAbbreviationCode": null,
      "cfdaNumber": null,
      "divisionDeptAcronym": null,
      "originalProgramId": null,
      "programDescription": null,
      "disasterFlag": null,
      "programOfficeId": null,
      "organizationId": null
    }]
  },
  {
    "roleId": 1,
    "code": "ORGAOR",
    "parentOrgId": null,
    "description": "Authorized Organization Representative",
    "displayText": "Authorized Organization Representative",
    "programs": [{
      "programId": 17,
      "programName": null,
      "programStatusId": null,
      "programTypeId": null,
      "startDate": null,
      "endDate": null,
      "financialAbbreviationCode": null,
      "cfdaNumber": null,
      "divisionDeptAcronym": null,
      "originalProgramId": null,
      "programDescription": null,
      "disasterFlag": null,
      "programOfficeId": null,
      "organizationId": null
    }]
  },
  {
    "roleId": 21,
    "code": "SUBAUTHREP",
    "parentOrgId": "-50022",
    "description": "Subrecipient Authorized Representative",
    "displayText": "Subrecipient Authorized Representative",
    "programs": [{
      "programId": 16,
      "programName": null,
      "programStatusId": null,
      "programTypeId": null,
      "startDate": null,
      "endDate": null,
      "financialAbbreviationCode": null,
      "cfdaNumber": null,
      "divisionDeptAcronym": null,
      "originalProgramId": null,
      "programDescription": null,
      "disasterFlag": null,
      "programOfficeId": null,
      "organizationId": null
    }]
  },
]

let nullprogramId;
nullprogramId = roles.some(r => r.programs.some(p => p.programId === null));
console.log(nullprogramId);
roles[0].programs[0].programId = null;
nullprogramId = roles.some(r => r.programs.some(p => p.programId === null));
console.log(nullprogramId);
```

Answer (score 0):

try using another .map on programs it would be something like this

```
updateUser = async (selectedUser) => {
    const {roles} = selectedUser;
    const newRoles =  roles.map((role) => {
      return role.programs.map(program => program.programId || -1);
    })
    console.log(newRoles);
 };
```

but it's not really clear what you want to do because that will change the answer alot

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get an object with all the objects that have programId of null you can use forEach like this. I am mentioning this options because its not really clear what you need.

```
const programsWithNullId = {};

roles.forEach(item=> item.programs.forEach((program,index) => {
if (program.programId ===null) {
programsWithNullId[`RoleID${item.roleId}atPosition${index+1}`]=program;
}
}));
```